# VS Code не запускает .js файл

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

При нажатии ctrl F5 запускался .js файл, однако в последнее время (скорее всего, после установки bun) оно перестало работать. И сейчас консоль откладки пуста, а при запуске не работают данные кнопки

[image]